# query mongoDb to substract timestamp

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, date, timestamp

I want a query to subtract day from a Date.
I test this:

`{"lastSeen": { "$gte": {"$date": { $subtract: [ "$date", 1616000000 ] }}}}`

But doesn't work. I have this error on Gamesparks.
`Error parsing JSON. Please use valid JSON, including double-quotes on object keys.`

Any ideas. Thank you.

Comment: "$subtract" in quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a JSON file, you will need to put $subtract in quotes.

```
{"lastSeen": { "$gte": {"$date": { "$subtract": [ "$date", 1616000000 ] }}}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The query is valid with quote on object. But the data base say 'no data to show'. I think i compare with a wrong data. I will see that tomorrow.